# Convert a Ruby string to proper Date and Time

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have a Ruby variable containing Timestamp , I need to get Date and Time from it , I am able to get Date (but wrong) time is always 00:00 (note: `li` is a variable getting from a file)

```
li = 'Date: Wed, 25 Dec 2019 23:16:52 -0600'
date = li.delete("Date: ")
  => "Wd,25c2019231652-0600"
puts date
  Wd,25c2019231652-0600
Date.parse(date).to_s
  => "2020-09-25"
Time.parse(date).to_s
  => "2020-09-25 00:00:00 +0530"
DateTime.parse(date).to_s
  => "2020-09-25T00:00:00+00:00"
DateTime.parse(date).strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
  => "2020-25-09 00:00:00"
```

I need to get correct date and Time (either in UTC or -0600)

Comment: Notice that when you say `delete("Date: ")`, you're not just removing the first 6 characters from your `li` string. You're removing every instance of the characters `D`, `a`, `t`, etc., which is mangling your `li` string prior to attempting to parse it.

Comment: My bad , I am unaware that how delete function working ,Now I am able to process

Answer (score 1):

```
li = 'Date: Wed, 25 Dec 2019 23:16:52 -0600'
```

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime(li, 'Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
  #=> #<Date: 2019-12-25 ((2458843j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

See [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime). Date-time formatting directives are given in the doc [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: Thanks for you comment, ```strptime``` is much better than ```parse``` indeed.